# Why is "[youtube-dl -f "bestvideo[height<=1080]+bestaudio/best[height<=1080]" ytlink]" not working in a Windows batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt, youtube-dl

I made a batch file which contains:-

```
set /p ytlink="Enter the link of Youtube Video:-  "  
youtube-dl -f "bestvideo[height<=1080]+bestaudio/best[height<=1080]" ytlink  
pause
```

But the output i got is:-

```
ERROR: 'ytlink' is not a valid URL. Set --default-search "ytsearch" (or run  youtube-dl "ytsearch:ytlink" ) to search YouTube
```

My aim is to make a batch file in which i can enter youtube link which it will download.

Comment: In batch, past the first space the `set` syntax for getting the output doesn't work. You have to make it with a `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You currently simply pass the text `ytlink` to youtube-dl. To pass the *content* of the `ytlink` variable, use `%ytlink%`.

```
set /p ytlink="Enter the link of Youtube Video:-  "  
youtube-dl -f "bestvideo[height<=1080]+bestaudio/best[height<=1080]" %ytlink%  
pause
```

Comment: Thanks and Why is output file named with (ext)s.webm when using -o "D:\Videos\%(title)s.%(ext)s"

Comment: I am not too experienced with Windows but you could try using single quotes instead of double quotes: `'D:\Videos\%(title)s.%(ext)s'`

Comment: @ByteHamster no that won't work because single quote is not a quoting character in cmd. \@sub1996 `%` is the character for variable substitution. The part between two `%` is the variable name, just like `%ytlink%`, so cmd will replace `%(title)s.%` with the corresponding variable, but since it doesn't exist, you're left with `(ext)s`

Comment: This works for me. `yt-dlp.exe -f "bestvideo[height<=?1080][ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[height<=?1080]" %URL%`